# How to extract array elements from json string in hive table?

Tags: hive, user-defined-functions

I have a hive table which contains a json string:

| column |
| --- |
| {"id": 123, "ShortName":"test tax","LongName":"test","Description":"test","aFactor":"true","bFactor":"true","cFactor":"false"} |
| {"id": 456, "ShortName":"test tax","LongName":"test","Description":"test","aFactor":"false","bFactor":"true","cFactor":"true"} |
| {"id": 678, "ShortName":"test tax","LongName":"test","Description":"test","aFactor":"false","cFactor":"true"} |

I want to create an array from this where ever aFactor, bFactor or cFactor is True:

| id | factors |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | aFactor,bFactor |
| 456 | bFactor,cFactor |
| 678 | cFactor |

being false or null is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using below steps -

1. first of all determine where are *Factor fields.
2. use if they are true and then concat them
   Whole query should look like below -

```
select get_json_object(str,'$.id') as id,
if(get_json_object(str,'$.aFactor')='true','aFactor','') ||if(get_json_object(str,'$.bFactor')='true',',bFactor','')||if(get_json_object(str,'$.cFactor')='true',',cFactor','') factors
from mytable
```

Sample result is in screenshot.
Test Query

```
with tab as ( select '{"id": 123, "ShortName":"test tax","LongName":"test","Description":"test","aFactor":"true","bFactor":"true","cFactor":"false"}' str)
select get_json_object(str,'$.id') as id,
if(get_json_object(str,'$.aFactor')='true','aFactor','') ||  
if(get_json_object(str,'$.bFactor')='true',',bFactor','') ||
if(get_json_object(str,'$.cFactor')='true',',cFactor','') 
 factors
```

[image: Sample Result]